# Speak the password and enter, if you dare

Tags: knowledge, password, mazes

Speak the password and enter, if you dare.

Can you find a logical path through the maze and explain why it is correct? What is the password?

Rules:

- must visit each square at least one time (or more)
- orthogonal movement only
- no immediate backtracking
- first names only

```
IN>agalewndromir
   zonromenoraro
   rodonelavoceb
   ?lahadrlebelr
   da?io?eegrami
   aggwemasogrin
   kanirryalero?
   lsarunavemond
   uthomnarnlguw
   loguamsadaada
   llidnellicnll
   uworarualegii
   myev?aegmothn
   anwesoisoronu
   rolduraluieet
   ?siuimhithnih>OUT
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Phew, this took some perseverance! The route through the maze traces the following overlapping path:

> [image: Route through the maze]

To navigate it, we must trace out:

> a chain of **[character names](https://www.behindthename.com/namesakes/list/tolkien/alpha) from the books of [J.R.R. Tolkien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._R._R._Tolkien)**, where the last letter of one name becomes the first letter of the next.
>
>  The characters who appear are (in order):
>
>  IN > Azog, Gandal**f**, **F**rodo, Oromë, Elenwë, Elrohi**r**, **R**adagast, Tulkas, Saruman, Nellas, Smaug, Gollum, Manwë, Éowyn, Nor**i**, **I**s(u)ldur, Ros**e**, **E**ärendil, Lotho, Ori, Ingwio**n**, **N**erdanel, Landroval, Legolas, Sam, Merry, Yavanna, Arveleg, Gríma, Argeleb, Boromir, Rorimac, Celebrin**d**or, Romendacil, Laura, Arvedui, Imrahil, Luthien, Niënor, Rosie, Egalmoth, Hilda, Angelica, Algund, Dwalin, Nuneth > OUT
>
>  (Letters in **bold** here are those which must replace the question marks.)

Which means the password - spelled out by the letters hidden behind the question marks, in the order we encounter them - is:

> **FRIEND**, which is a reference to an event in *Lord of the Rings* where the [West-door of Moria](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Doors_of_Durin) bears an inscription with the instruction to "speak 'friend' and enter" (hence the title here!). Once Gandalf does so, the gate opens!

Comment: Great perseverance! Good spot on the typo; fixed!

Comment: Nice answer. May I know your thought process?

Comment: @justhalf Sure: rot13(Xabjvat gung jr jrer ybbxvat sbe 'svefg anzrf' uvqqra va gur tevq, gurer qvqa'g frrz gb or znal 'abezny' anzrf uvqqra jvguva, pregnvayl abar V pbhyq fcbg yrnqvat gb gur 'BHG'. Ybbxvat ng gur 'VA' V ernyvfrq gung 'NMBT' jnf n punenpgre sebz Gur Uboovg; gura V erpbtavfrq gur 'fcrnx... naq ragre' dhbgr sebz YbgE. Gura fcbggvat OBEBZVE gbc evtug, naq QJNYVA qbja gur fvqr, V ernyvfrq V jnf ba gb fbzrguvat. TNAQNYS naq SEBQB sryy, haqre gur nffhzcgvba gung gur dhrfgvba znex fubhyq or na S, naq gura gur fgneg-naq-raq angher bs gur znmr ebhgr orpnzr pyrne.)

Comment: rot13(Vg gbbx n YBG bs pbafhygvat gur yvaxrq jrocntr gb vqragvsl gur zber bofpher punenpgref, naq gura svanyyl V unq n ebhgr gung sryy vagb cynpr!)